# Which array declaration increases software maintainability

Tags: java, android, arrays, xml

So after doing a bit of research on Java arrays I am aware that you can declare arrays like so in a Java file:

```
String[] myStringArray = new String[3];
String[] myStringArray = {“a”,”b”,”c”};
String[] myStringArray = new String[]{“a”,”b”,”c”};
```

And you can also declare an array as a resource in the `array.xml` file of an Android app like so:

```
<string-array name = "fruit_array">
    <item> Apple </item>
    <item> Orange </item>
    <item> Pear </item>
</string-array>
```

But what I want to know is which declartion option is best for increasing software maintainability?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The XML resource files are easier to translate. So I would say:

- If you have strings that should be displayed to the user (e.g. names of something) you write them in a XML file so you can translate them easily.
- If you have strings that are only used in the app and never displayed (e.g. names for options in a Bundle or so) you should use Java-Arrays.

Of course, if you don't plan to translate your app, you don't need to write everything in a XML file.

Comment: Assumptions about the future are usually nil, so I would go with the more flexible option if the "cost" in terms of work isn't mentionably higher.

Answer (score 1):

Nothing differs at all. It's a matter of your preference, you can do whatever you want. But defining them in a xml file will be better if you are going to make your app multilingual with many different translations.

**In code:**

```
String[] fruitArray = {“Apple”, ”Orange”, ”Pear”};
```

**In arrays.xml or strings.xml:**

```
<string-array name = "fruit_array">
    <item>Apple</item>
    <item>Orange</item>
    <item>Pear</item>
</string-array>
```

Then receive it in code like:

```
String[] fruitArray = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.fruit_array);
```